# Created a e-mail chain around Project Status Held and Expiry dates

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom-list

[image: Workflow as seen in SP Designer]

I have created a custom list that tracks projects and within this created a workflow that will send an e-mail to a certain user if the Project Status is changed to Hold. Then when the Hold Expiry date is reached to send another set of e-mails and return to the status back to work in progress.

I ran the test yesterday with a pause date of today 27 May
Start Option is set as Allow this workflow to be manually started and Start workflow automatically when item is changed. 
I have checked the date and time where server are based and its 27 May so the Held status should have expired, but on checking the project tracker the project is still on hold and no e-mails have been fired off.

With the Pause Date set as Today 27 May, will the workflow wait until 28 May to start the workflow?

Comment: It looks like it should work, but I'm down-voting your question because the point of this site is to ask questions *after* you've already tried and gotten stuck. If this workflow doesn't work, edit your question to tell us which part didn't work as expected and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Erin - It didn't work see above for more details

Comment: What's the current status of the workflow?

Comment: The workflow isn't firing at all

Comment: Correction - Its fired and completed but the Hold Expiry Date was 27/05/2016, but it didn't start until 31/05/2016 (Do workflows not fire at weekends and public holidays)

Comment: That's very strange. There's a timer job setting in central admin that determines how frequently workflows are checked for waiting or pausing. I believe it's set to 5 minutes by default, and it's an increment so there's no way it could know to skip weekend and holidays. I have had paused workflows not resume if the workflow engine was overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason it wouldn't work as shown. Does it work in practice if you actually run it? That's the real test after all.  ;)